# Why error "FS0239 an implementation of the file or module has already been given"?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Visual Studio is underlining the F# code in one of my source files with a red squiggly. The error message reads, "FS0239 an implementation of the file or module ________ has already been given."

When I search the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, there is only one file or module with the supposedly duplicate name.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my *.fsproj file had several lines duplicated, like this:

```
    <Compile Include="File1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="File2.fs" />
    <Compile Include="File3.fs" />
    <Compile Include="File1.fs" />
    <Compile Include="File2.fs" />
    <Compile Include="File3.fs" />
```

Removing the duplicates fixed the problem.

As a side note, I think the duplication was caused by a Git merge.